# Linux on Lenovo W541, problems with Nvidia driver

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, thinkpad, nvidia-graphics-card

Trying to get Linux Mint 17.2 installed on my new Lenovo W541 refresh.
The installation works fine with the Nouveau graphics.
But Nouveau doesn't do well with additional displays attached to the dock.

Blacklisted Nouveau and installed Nvidia driver from their [ftp site](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/355.11/).

But nvidia-settings then always complains

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run
`nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
```

Did that, but no help.

It appears to me the culprit is the additional Intel GPU.

```
$ lshw -c video | grep config
    configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Unlike with the W530, the Intel GPU can't seem to be disabled in the BIOS ([lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-W-Series-Laptops/Why-does-my-Thinkpad-W541-use-Integrated-graphics-in-WoW-instead/td-p/2042979)).
There's nothing in the BIOS which seems to do the trick :-(

Anyone got this solved?

Comment: did you resolve this?
https://mbogochow.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/linux-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-w541/
seems to suggest that it is possible to get it working

Comment: By default the nvidia-xconfig command doesnt show all options.. Have you looked into nvidia-xconfig -A --help by chance?

Comment: any updates with the multi-monitor situation?